# Is there a clever way to work on several views in a single viewport using storyboard in Xcode 6?

Tags: storyboard, view, xcode6

My app has multiple views in a single viewport that are animated to move into the display on request (setting menus, messages etc.). Currently, they are all located on top of each other, which is a bit cumbersome if you want to edit them. I have to drag each viewport on top, which will hide the others.

Is there a clever way to see the separate views next to another in the storyboard of Xcode 6, even though they are all in the same view controller?